# iOS - Collection View cells is not appearing on Orientation Change

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview

I have generated all the cell on first time when the view load using.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [dataArray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    NSString *rowStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d", indexPath.row, indexPath.section, nil];
    CollectionCell *cell;

        cell = [collectionVw dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"xxxx" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     ...........
   }
```

and just get the cell on the following function.

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath               
  { 
            if(cellsDict != nil && cellsDict.count > 0)
            {
                return [cellsDict objectForKey:rowStr];
            }
         }
```

First time it works fine, but when I change the orientation it does not show some cells.

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: have you tried to implement the frame change when delegate method for orientation change is called?

Comment: Check for the collection view autosizing in xib.

Comment: I have changed the size of collection view on orientation change. but still some cells are missing. Some are missing from middle and some are from end.